# How can I make the huggingface cache variable HF_HOME work?

Tags: environment-variables, cache-control, huggingface

I was trying to change the huggingface default cache folder, and I found a article said that set the HF_HOME varibale can deal with it.
Then I added the variable in Windows Enviroment Variable, and reboot my computer. After that, I download a model from huggface, but the cache didn't go to the place that I set, it still in the default address.
I was trying to do this on win11.

I try to reboot again and change the HF_HOME, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It turns out that the System Variable that I used to set is not the correct variable, I need to set the User Variable to make it work.